# How do I output to the following format: month - year?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Today's month is November (11). With `1.years.ago.to_date..Date.today` how can I output:

11 - 2010, 12 - 2010, 01 - 2011, 02 - 2011, 03 - 2011, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strftime
```

Use function for all date modifications in ruby

Refer This [DOC](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

Comment: Sorry but the answer is incomplete... I know about strftime. How does it fit into `1.years.ago.to_date..Date.today` to output the desired results?

Comment: just chain the method on, e.g. 1.years.ago.to_date.Date.today.strftime("%m-%Y")  Note we are trying to help and guide not usually just write the final code.

Comment: @ChristianFazzini: Your question title asks only about formatting. If you want a way to iterate by month, check this SO question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1724735/82592

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but this will give you the output you want:

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

((1.year.ago.to_date)..(Date.today)).map { |d| d.strftime("%m-%Y") }.uniq!
```

Answer (score 0):

For print date used strtotime() function.

//For today print a date used the following code

```
echo date('m/d/Y',strtotime("today"));
```

//For one year ago print a date used the following code

```
echo date('m.d.Y',strtotime("-1 years"));
```

//For coming year date from today used following code

```
echo date('m.d.Y',strtotime("1 years"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to add a new format to your locales.

```
#/config/locales/en.yml
en:
  date:
    formats:
      month_year: "%m - %Y"
```

and to use it with `I18n.l(your_date, :format => :month_year)`

This will help if you want to change the format later, you will change in a unique point.